# VHDL simple Moore state machine

Tags: vhdl, state-machine

I'm working on simple Moore state machine, with 2 states ON and OFF and an input signal switch that makes the transition between the states.

I'm testing it with a simple benchtest but the output is unitiliazed. I think it is because the initial state isnt declared. But I've done more complex state machine where I didn't initialized the state and it worked.

Does anyone know what is the mistakes? How can I see the states on the waveform? Do I need to initiliaze the first state?

Below are my code and benchtest. I tried to initialize the state in the benchtest but it didn't worked.

Thank you

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity mySM is port(
    switch : in std_logic;
    o : out std_logic);
end mySM;

architecture bhv of mySM is
    type stateType is (ON1, OFF);
    signal currentState : stateType;
    signal nextState : stateType;      
    begin
        
        process(switch) begin
            currentState <= nextState;
        end process;
       
        process(currentState) begin
                case currentState is 
                    when ON1 =>
                        nextState <= OFF; o <= '0';
                    when OFF =>
                        nextState <= ON1; o <= '1';
                end case;
        end process;
end bhv;


library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity StateMachine_tb is
end entity;

architecture behavior of StateMachine_tb is
    component StateMachine is 
        port(switch: in std_logic;
            o: out std_logic);
    end component;
    
    signal switch, o : std_logic;
    type stateType is (ON1, OFF);
    signal nextState : stateType;
    signal currentState : stateType; --:= OFF;

    begin
        uut : StateMachine port map(switch => switch, o => o);
        stim : process begin
            switch <= '0'; --currentState <= OFF;
            wait for 10 ns;
            switch <= '0';
            wait for 10 ns;
            switch <= '1';
            wait for 10 ns;
            switch <= '0';
            wait for 10 ns;
        end process;
end behavior;
```

Comment: The issue is uut: StateMachine is unbound. If you note the entity and architecture for the state machine assume the entity name is MySM. This likely should have shown up as a warning, it's not an error for a component to be unbound. There are two solutions either rename to match or take advantage of components being virtual and provide a binding indication with a configuration specification in the architecture block declarative region (before the begin) of the form `for uut: StateMachine use entity work.MySM;`

Comment: See [a testbench markup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqize.jpg). Note the process in MySM sensitive to switch events is not synthesis eligible. It operates on both transitions from '0' to '1' and '1' to '0'. (The red highlight signifies an error, a defect in the editor highlighter that does not actually parse VHDL, it's caused by the for in the configuration specification not having an end. VHDL is more complex that the highlighter authors or nouveau users might imagine. The highlighter attempts to enforce indenting which has no meaning in VHDL.)

Comment: @user1155120 Thank you for your answer. I though that having a wrong name would show up as an error. Good catch. Now that I have fixed that, I see that my switch is not working like you said, it operated from both rise/down edge. To fix it, I used rising_edge.

But I still don't get how does the circuit choose the initial state.

Comment: Good practice : add a Reset input, which (when asserted) forces the state to its initial value. Hacky (leading to un-resettable hardware): initialise it in the declaration.